# Selecting multiple translated articles (records)

Tags: mysql, database, localization

How do I select i.e. 10 articles without having to run 1 query to fetch each article translation (a total of 11 queries)? I have 3 tables; cultures, articles, and translations:

```
Cultures
id code language
-- ---- ---------
1  en   English
2  no   Norwegian

Articles
id title content      
-- ----- -------------
1  Home  Hello, world!
2  About This is me...
...

Translations
id culture object FK field   value
-- ------- ------ -- ------- ---------------
1  1       Page   1  title   Home
2  1       Page   1  content Hello, world!
3  2       Page   1  title   Hjem
4  2       Page   1  content Hei, verden!
5  1       Page   2  title   About
6  1       Page   2  content This is me...
7  2       Page   2  title   Om
8  2       Page   2  content Dette er meg...
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Say I want to fetch all the articles, translated to norwegian. This is my incomplete query (it does not YET connect FK to a.id):

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    (SELECT tr.value FROM translations tr WHERE tr.object='Page' 
AND field='title' AND tr.culture=2) as title,
    (SELECT tr.value FROM translations tr WHERE tr.object='Page' 
AND tr.field='content' AND tr.culture=2) as content
FROM
    articles a
```

Edit 2: Same issue as this:
[Best mysql query for selecting multiple rows that EACH need multiple associative rows from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654899/best-mysql-query-for-selecting-multiple-rows-that-each-need-multiple-associative)

Comment: Why would you want to fetch translations if you can just fetch articles?

Comment: @Konerak No, I'm lost, working on a client project, not super experienced, looking for help.

Comment: @piotrm Because in half of the cases I would like to fetch the translated articles.

Comment: Your query in your edit is... weird. The subqueries do not link to the main query (there is no articles `a` inside them). Are you sure you want to do that? Why a subquery when a join works fine?

Comment: @Konerak It would be great if you could keep the arrogance or whatever it is to yourself. My query is incomplete, as I stated above, it's there to make it clearer what I'm trying to achieve. If you're saying that the best solution is to fetch each article times number of translated fields, then I'm happy to accept that.

Comment: I'm sorry if I came over as arrogant. I'm trying to understand what you mean, what you want, how you think, so I can help you better. Which is not easy via text :)

Comment: @Konerak Apology accepted :) My problem was realizing that a solution with redundant results could be the optimal one. Think I was looking for something overly practical. Joins now seem illogically logical for the job :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `translations.FK` appears to be linked to the articles ID. So you select all articles, and for each article you select all translations.

With this query, your application code will then have to interpret the "title" / "content" stuff.

```
SELECT c.language, a.title, t.field, t.value
FROM articles a 
JOIN translations t ON a.ID = t.FK
JOIN cultures c on t.culture = c.id
```

With this query, you get  a 'title' and a 'content' column

```
SELECT a.title, t1.value as title, t2.value as content
FROM articles a 
JOIN translations t1 ON a.ID = t1.FK and t1.field = 'title'
JOIN translations t2 ON a.ID = t2.FK and t2.field = 'content'
```

Comment: This will result in X articles times number of translated fields. In this case 10x2 = 20. I understand that I can iterate through the results and get all the translated data, however, I'd like to do that in the query. Is that possible?

Comment: In which format do you want the 'translated data' then? If you have 10 articles and 5 languages, you will always get 50 resulting translations... there's nothing bad about that.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear before, but I'm curious as to whether there's a more compact approach; a way to fetch a specified amount of articles with the values from 'translations' already included in each row, for 1 specified language.

Comment: Thanks! The second query was what I was looking for.